# Question about proving corollary on multigraphs and Euler trails

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

From Applied Combinatorics, Tucker:
A multigraph has an Euler trail, but not an Euler cycle, if and only if it is connected and has exactly two vertices of odd degree.

In trying to prove the forwards direction myself, can't you imagine a multigraph that looks like two vertices, and the first vertex has a loop? In this case, it is a multigraph because there exist multiple edges joining the same pair of vertices, and there is an Euler trail (the loop) but not an Euler cycle.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say the loop is an Euler trail but not an Euler cycle? What is your definition of "Euler cycle"?

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book handy, but an Euler circuit (which some people call an Euler cycle, although the word cycle is usually reserved for circuits with no repeated vertices) is usually defined as an Euler trail which begins and ends at the same vertex, as your loop certainly does

Answer (score 2):

When you add a loop to a vertex, the degree goes up by *two*.  So you can add as many loops as you want from as many vertices as you want and it doesn't affect the parity of any vertices.  Therefore adding loops to an Eulerian graph results in an Eulerian graph.

Consider a graph with an Eulerian trail, and then add a loop to one vertex $v$.  Now traverse the Eulerian trail except when we reach $v$, we traverse the loop and then arrive back at $v$ and then continue with the Eulerian trail.  We traverse all edges including the loop we added.  Therefore, after adding a loop, the graph still has an Eulerian trail.  It's not hard to see that you can add as many loops as you want to as many vertices as you want and we still have an Eulerian trail in the graph.

In general, if the parity of each vertex is invariant under some operation $X$ then the Eulerian property is invariant under $X$ also.  (Only for connected graphs)

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea a loop made the degree go up by 2 - now this makes sense.